# Recognizing New Sheet as Last

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple workbooks running the same code, but behaving differently.

I think a user manually moved worksheets; changing the order.

The code uses

```vb
tempWs.Copy after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

to copy a template sheet to the end of the workbook.

However, when running the following code in another module, the workbook seems to not recognize which sheet is the last sheet:

```
lastSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
....
ws.Cells(i,2).value = Worksheets(lastSh).Name
```

In some workbooks, the above code, as expected, returns the name of the last sheet (the newly created one).
In the workbooks with the odd behavior, lastSh points to the same sheet every time rather than recognizing I added another.

Another oddity: when I tried recreating the workbook by copying sheets from the erroring book to a new one, the error persists to that new version.

Why is the index of sheets seemingly stagnant or is my ".Copy after:=" doing something I don't know about?

```vb
Sub addToSummary()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i, lastSh, lastRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
lastSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
lastRow = ws.Range("B6").End(xlDown).Row + 1

If ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = "Total Amount Paid:" Then
    Call addRow 'adds a row on a summary sheet if needed
    ws.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = Worksheets(lastSh).Name
Else
    ws.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = Worksheets(lastSh).Name
End If

ws.Cells(lastRow, 3).Formula = "='" + Worksheets(lastSh).Name + "'!currentPay"

End Sub
```

Regardless of creating a new file, this code is referencing the same sheet.

Comment: Does `tempWs` belong to the `ActiveWorkbook`? Using `lastSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` followed by `ws.Cells(i,2).value = Worksheets(lastSh).Name` may not do what you think, if in the moment of code running `ThisWorkbook` is not the `ActiveWorkbook`... It is recommended to fully qualify the used objects, at least, use them referring the same workbook. Or `ActiveWorkbook`, or `ThisWorkbook`. I never heard about the possibility of sheet index failing.

Comment: @FaneDuru yes.  `tempWs` does belong to the `ActiveWorkbook` during the running of that code. The entire project runs as expected in all workbooks created from the original file save 2 that I've been notified of.

Comment: And yes, when running the code `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook` are the same workbook. I do create another file during the chain, but that workbook is closed before the code returns to the second set of commands.

Comment: Can you share the code doing what you say? Are you sure that the moment of sheet copying is not before the created workbook is closed?

Comment: @FaneDuru I added the block that gets the error.  In the current file with the problem, this happens regardless of whether I am adding a sheet or not. It pulls the name of the incorrect sheet each time I run this.

Comment: So, after running a test, I have the following index of sheets (that matter). `Sheet11(core...)` and `Sheet12(test)` are the last ones.  But, `Worksheets(lastSh).Name` returns the name of `Sheet11`.  During debugging, `lastSh` is 12?

Comment: Even if this code is always referring to the same workbook it would still be good to qualify every Sheets/Worksheets call with an explicit workbook object. Edit - I see this point was already made...

Comment: Have you tried using `DoEvents` or `Workbook.RefreshAll` before referencing `lastSh` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
tempWs.Copy after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

The number of *sheets* is not necessarily the same as the number of *worksheets*. If you have a chart sheet and 3 worksheets then `Worksheets.Count` is 3 but you have 4 Sheets so the sheet gets copied *before* the last sheet.

So you probably wanted this:

```
tempWs.Copy after:=ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim.  I tried changing that snip of code, yet the problem remains.  I added another block of code at the end of the question that focuses more on the actual issue.  Sorry for the poor organization of the question before.  It seems my sheet index is just plain stuck.  With a current index of `Sheet11(core...)` and `Sheet12(test)`, as I debug the script, `lastSh` is actually "12", yet the `Worksheets(lastSh).Name` section returns the name of `Sheet11(core...)`. There are no other objects in the file other than Worksheets.

Comment: Any hidden/very hidden sheets?

Comment: And see my comment above.

Comment: Yeeeep. 1 very hidden, lots of hidden. Even if I unhide them all, it still pulls the wrong one for some reason.  The weird part is, this is only happening in a couple files built off the same code.  I have 25+ other files working just fine..... for now. And that scares me!

Comment: Are you able to share a workbook which reproduces the problem?  Or are you able to create one which reproduces it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, either the sharing or even reproducing the error.

Comment: If you're willing to share via dropbox or even email then I think that's acceptable here.  Depends on whether your problem workbook contains sensitive info, but you should be able to delete most of the content without affecting the core problem...